# How to install PHP 5.2.x on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, php, versions

I want to run a version specific code on php 5.2.x which I have tried by many ways but not got any successful attempt.

Please let me know that how I can install PHP 5.2 on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: download all files from http://thejibe.com/blog/10/5/php-5210-debs-ubuntu-104-lucid and install them manually by sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb

Answer (score 5):

## Install PHP 5.2.17 on Ubuntu 14.04

Based on:

http://www.rasyid.net/2014/10/07/using-multiple-php-inside-one-ubuntu-machine/

---

### Add PostgreSQL Apt Repository (provides postgresql-server-dev-9.4)

```
apt-get install -y wget
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

### Install dependencies

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y gcc make build-essential \
    libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libpcre3-dev libbz2-dev libjpeg-    dev \
    libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev libt1-dev libmcrypt-dev libmhash-dev \
    freetds-dev libmysqlclient-dev unixodbc-dev postgresql-server-dev-9.4 \
    libxslt1-dev
```

### Required to prevent an issue when compiling freetype support

```
mkdir -pv /usr/include/freetype2/freetype
ln -sf /usr/include/freetype2/freetype.h /usr/include/freetype2/freetype/freetype.h
```

### Download PHP sources

```
wget -c -t 3 -O ./php-5.2.17.tar.gz http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.17.tar.gz
tar xvfz php-5.2.17.tar.gz
cd php-5.2.17
```

### Patch PHP

```
wget -c -t 3 -O ./libxml29_compat.patch https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2012-August/txtbgxGXAvz4N.txt
patch -p0 -b < libxml29_compat.patch

wget -c -t 3 -O ./debian_patches_disable_SSLv2_for_openssl_1_0_0.patch https://bugs.php.net/patch-display.php\?bug_id\=54736\&patch\=debian_patches_disable_SSLv2_for_openssl_1_0_0.patch\&revision=1305414559\&download\=1
patch -p1 -b < debian_patches_disable_SSLv2_for_openssl_1_0_0.patch

wget -c -t 3 -O - http://php-fpm.org/downloads/php-5.2.17-fpm-0.5.14.diff.gz | gunzip > ./php-5.2.17-fpm-0.5.14.patch
patch -p1 < php-5.2.17-fpm-0.5.14.patch
```

### Compile and install

```
./configure \
    --prefix=/usr/share/php52 \
    --datadir=/usr/share/php52 \
    --mandir=/usr/share/man \
    --bindir=/usr/bin/php52 \
    --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --includedir=/usr/include \
    --with-config-file-path=$PHP_HOME/etc \
    --with-config-file-scan-dir=$PHP_HOME/etc/conf.d \
    --disable-debug \
    --with-regex=php \
    --disable-rpath \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-posix \
    --with-pic \
    --with-layout=GNU \
    --with-pear=/usr/share/php \
    --enable-calendar \
    --enable-sysvsem \
    --enable-sysvshm \
    --enable-sysvmsg \
    --enable-bcmath \
    --with-bz2 \
    --enable-ctype \
    --without-gdbm \
    --with-iconv \
    --enable-exif \
    --enable-ftp \
    --enable-cli \
    --with-gettext \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --with-pcre-regex \
    --enable-shmop \
    --enable-sockets \
    --enable-wddx \
    --enable-fastcgi \
    --enable-force-cgi-redirect \
    --enable-fpm \
    --with-mcrypt \
    --with-zlib \
    --enable-pdo \
    --with-curl \
    --enable-inline-optimization \
    --enable-xml \
    --enable-pcntl \
    --enable-mbregex \
    --with-mhash \
    --with-xsl \
    --enable-zip \
    --with-gd \
    --with-pdo-mysql \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
    --with-png-dir=/usr/lib \
    --with-mysql \
    --with-openssl \
    --with-mysqli \
    --with-kerberos \
    --enable-dbase \
    --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --with-t1lib=/usr \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr \
    --with-ldap \
    --with-kerberos=/usr \
    --with-unixODBC=shared,/usr \
    --with-imap-ssl \
    --with-mssql \
    --without-sqlite \
    --with-sqlite \
    --without-pdo-sqlite \
    --with-pgsql \
    --with-pdo-pgsql \
    --enable-soap \
    --with-pdo-sqlite

make
make install
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) instead of just `make install`.

Comment: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Answer (score -1):

You can make Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) use the packages from Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala) to easily install PHP 5.2. This is how I installed PHP 5.2.10 on Ubuntu 14.04.3.

**Step 1**

Create a file `karmic.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and add the following:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates universe

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ karmic-updates multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu karmic-security multiverse
```

**Step 2**

Then, create another file `php5_2` in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` with the following:

```
Package: apache2*
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: libapache2-mod-php5
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: libapache2-mod-php5filter
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php-pear
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-cgi
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-cli
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-common
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-curl
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-dbg
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-dev
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-gd
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-gmp
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-mhash
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-mysql
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-odbc
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-pgsql
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-pspell
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-recode
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-snmp
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-sqlite
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-sybase
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-tidy
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-xmlrpc
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991

Package: php5-xsl
Pin: release a=karmic
Pin-Priority: 991
```

**Step 3**

Then, run `sudo apt-get update` and finally, install them by using the following (example):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php-pear php5-curl php5-dbg php5-mhash php5-mysql php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

*p/s: You could add other php extensions in the install command above, but only the ones defined in the `php5_2` preference file, otherwise it will install the wrong version.*

Comment: Mixing Ubuntu releases is asking for pain. -1